# Caching FullHttpResponse as ByteBuf

Tags: performance, netty

Is there a way to build a `FullHttpResponse` and convert it into a bytebuf using some public Netty API?
I don't want only the `content` but the complete response bytebuf.
I want to do this to cache the HttpResponse.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could use `EmbeddedChannel` with the `HttpResponseEncoder` in the pipeline. Then you could just call `writeOutbound(...)` and then `readOutbound` to read the `ByteBuf`s.

Comment: Also you might just consider caching the whole object and just call `retainedDuplicate()` on the cached object when you pass to the pipeline. That said in this case you will still need to convert it to a `ByteBuf` on each write which might be not what you want

Comment: This is a possible solution. Can a new public API not be written to achieve this?

Comment: I done think we want to add another API for this as like you said it is already possible